# Odoo14 | No record found for unique ID base.user_admin

Tags: odoo-14

Accidently the user with **id=2** which is (**admin**) deleted.How we can recover/fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Create xml record again with that xml ID.

```
    <record id="base.user_admin" model="res.users">
        <field name="login">admin</field>
        <field name="password">admin</field>
        <field name="partner_id" ref="base.partner_admin"/>
        <field name="company_id" ref="main_company"/>
        <field name="company_ids" eval="[(4, ref('main_company'))]"/>
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,[])]"/>
        <field name="signature"><![CDATA[<span>-- <br/>Administrator</span>]]></field>
    </record>
```